# Ubuntu 22.04 - Two of the same digital cameras, but only one is detected?

Tags: 22.04, camera

I have a desktop with Ubuntu 22.04 and two Canon Ti7 DLSR cameras connected to it by USB. Both are recognized as USB devices, but only the one plugged in first appears for the user. I have tried replacing one of the cameras with a similar, but not the same camera, but the problem still persisted. Furthermore, this setup has worked before with previous Ubuntu versions. Has anyone else encountered this issue and/or have a solution to this issue?

Comment: 1. Try plugging the second camera which is not detecting with the first port (which is working) to see if the problem is with port. 2. Run **lsusb** and **lsblk** command to see if both the camera devices are listed there.

Comment: I've tried plugging the cameras in different ports and the problem is not the ports. lsusb lists both cameras, but not lsblk. However, only one camera's photos appears in the files

Comment: Please for once update and reboot your system, and try plugging them again.

Comment: The system is updated and has been rebooted, but the issue still persists.